# Node js net socket waits 5 seconds before firing data event

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp

I am facing same issue as mentioned in this question
[Node.js TCP socket waits seconds before polling? (net.createServer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405603/node-js-tcp-socket-waits-seconds-before-polling-net-createserver)

I tried the answer marked as correct here but not able to understand how it is helpful. By adding that line "sock.write(data);" inside the "sock.on('data', function(data)" event, my "TELLER" goes into infinite loop.

Can anyone please help me understand what I am doing wrong?

Here is my code,

```
    server.on('connection', function (sock) {
    console.log('CONNECTED: ' + sock.remoteAddress + ':' + sock.remotePort);
    sock.setNoDelay(true);

    sock.on('error', function (err) {
        console.log("ERROR : " + err.toString());
    });

    sock.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log(moment().format("HH:mm:ss") + ' DATA : ' + sock.remoteAddress + ': ' + data);
        data = data.toString().trim();

        if (data.indexOf("MY_DATA_DELIMITER") > -1) {
            console.log(moment().format("HH:mm:ss") + ' sending a command');

            sock.write("MY_COMMAND");
        ////////// I get a response of this write after 5 seconds
        }

    });

    sock.on('close', function (data) {
        console.log('CLOSED: ' + sock.remoteAddress + ' ' + sock.remotePort);
    });

    sock.on('end', function () {
        console.log('ENDED : ' + sock.remoteAddress + ' ' + sock.remotePort);
    });
});
```

In the data event, when I receive a string containing MY_DATA_DELIMITER, I send a COMMAND (just a string not more than 50 characters). The client, as a response to this COMMAND, sends a REPLY. I get this REPLY exactly after 5 seconds.

Comment: How about posting your code so that people can take a look at what you are doing wrong?

Comment: Added code, please check if anything you can guide me to.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be the way it is handled in CLIENT program. I do not have control over the CLIENT program hence it took much time to debug & figure out what is causing the delay.
The CLIENT expects a line ending with each message as the delimiter.
Though the example code I shared here uses line ending with message, I missed sending that in my actual code.

Hence the CLIENT kept waiting to detect end of message & this waiting took 5 seconds.

Now when I send the line ending character with each message, it is working without any delay.

Thank you for your time to look at it.